# Problem After Upgrading to Ubuntu 15.04 ( deal with any system changes..P link was shut down )

Tags: lightdm

I have laptop Sony VAIO with ubuntu 14.04 i upgrade it to 14.10 then after that i upgrade it to 15.04 .Upon the upgrading complete and the laptop restart ,A blank screen appears and at the end of it saying that "starting light display manager...and deal with any system changes..P link was shut down "

can any one help so that not reinstall the system :(

Answer (score 0):

Reposting from https://askubuntu.com/a/679889/323093:

You will get more details when running gdm manually in a virtual console (`Ctrl` + `Alt` + `F1`):

```
sudo gdm
```

For me, the problem was that gdm wasn't able to find /usr/bin/X, which led me to [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-server/+bug/737651). Turns out xserver-xorg was not installed somehow. The following line solves this particular problem.

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg
```

Hope this helps.