# Ubuntu 15.04 boot hangs on "Starting light display manager" after updates

Tags: boot, 15.04, lightdm

I have recently taken the plunge to Ubuntu, and purchased the Dell XPS 13 Developer Edition. My first order of business was to wipe the "Dellbuntu" that came pre-installed and do a fresh install of 15.04. After some minor hiccups and googling I had a working installation of 15.04 for about a day. Then I was prompted to install some updates via the built in update manager and everything installed correctly, but I needed to reboot. Now, upon rebooting, and selecting my distro in GRUB, I am greeted by many lines of scrolling text, all prefaced with the green `[OK]` tag, except the last one which reads:

```
Starting Light Display Manager ... and deal with any system changes ..
```

Upon which the boot hangs with a flashing underscore, and never moves.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Any chance you could take a photograph of your screen and upload that here? It might be useful to see the previous error messages, although my guess is that a more serious error message (ending in "and deal with any system changes ..") that is being partially obscured by the "Starting Light Display Manager ..." message.

Also: you're not the only one with this error! --> http://askubuntu.com/questions/636524/problem-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-15-04-deal-with-any-system-changes-p-link-w

Answer (score 10):

Try to go to **tty1** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>)

Login and purge `xorg` and `lightdm`

```
sudo apt-get purge xorg lightdm
```

Autoremove whatever's left

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Install lightdm and xorg

```
sudo apt-get install xorg lightdm
```

Comment: When apt refuses to install the packages because you have held packages you can do as follows (this is what I've did):

`sudo aptitude -f install xorg lightdm ubuntu-desktop`

It will tell you a little bit more than apt. Do not use the solutions to hold the XServer-*LTS packages. (Try other options) And choose do install X-Server-Core (yes the new one)

´sudo service lightdm restart´
or
`reboot`
(I got exactly this problem. In the first place I was afraid by removing X-Org LightDm because it will remove ubuntu-desktop too but mow all is up and running again) (improve answer did not work)

Comment: After 2 sleepless days, this surprisingly saved me. Thanks !!

Comment: did that & did apt-get update/upgrade. after that, 500 MB were downladed and now my entire operating system changed: from xubuntu to ubuntu. LOL

Answer (score 2):

There is an easier solution I think.
Try from client <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>f2</kbd> (<kbd>F1</kbd> might not work, as it is trying to boot)

Then run

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Comment: This is the correct answer

Answer (score 1):

If you have recently installed **Nvidia** Drivers, try removing them

Try to go to **tty1** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>)

1. Find all Nvidia packages installed

   ```
   apt list --installed | grep nvidia
   ```

   ex: there is a package named `nvidia-352`
2. Remove the packages found like

   ```
   sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove nvidia-352
   ```
3. After the removal is complete, try booting again to your Ubuntu system.