# `drm: intel_pipe_config_compare .. mismatch in ips_enabled (expected 1, found 0)` Error on boot [15.10 on a Macbook Pro 11,1]

Tags: boot, 15.10, intel, macbook, wpa-supplicant

I just got Ubuntu 15.10 installed on my mac machine. Initially everything works well.

Following [the help.ubuntu.com tutorial on fixing the touchpad (for utopic)](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookPro11-1/utopic), I installed a bunch of things and did some config. After that I restarted `lightdm` with

```
systemctl restart lightdm
```

which consequently did a reboot. But it got stuck at shutting down so I ended up forcing the shut-down. When I re-started it I kept seeing many lines of

```
 [drm: intel_pipe_config_compare [i915]] *ERROR* mismatch in ips_enabled (expected 1, found 0)
```

while starting `WPA supplicant` in the process of starting `Light Display Manager` and was not able to boot into Ubuntu. I tried rebooting it many times but I was greeted by the same error.

[image]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

What is going on? Without reinstalling Ubuntu, is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After plugging in a usb keyboard and getting into tty2 with `Control+ alt + F2` (since I couldn't produce `alt` and/or `F2` output on the Macbook P keyboard), I tried [purging & reinstalling xorg and lightdm as suggested in this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/638850/ubuntu-15-04-boot-hangs-on-starting-light-display-manager-after-updates) but to no avail.

So I decided to start removing everything I installed on Ubuntu before encountering this error.. and (finally!) I managed to boot into ubuntu again by getting rid of `bcmwl-kernel-source` for the wifi:

```
sudo apt-get remove bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Hmmm. Now I'd need to figure out why `bcmwl-kernel-source` is causing this error.

Comment: I get the same lines in my `dmesg`, but don't have that package installed. See also https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1492764

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem on my Lenovo laptop, every time my Ubuntu starts it shows this error and displays Ubuntu running in low graphic mode.

Then, after a bit struggling I am not getting the solution, so as a random thought I removed my latest installed softwares and My Ubuntu is back to work.

Steps I followed:

1. When the error popped up, I pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>, it opened virtual terminal and I entered my login and password.
2. Then used this command:

   ```
   history | grep install
   ```

   After this output showed, what all software packages I had recently installed. Mine showed `fdlrx`, `xdm`, `openvpn`.
3. Removed those packages using:

   ```
   sudo apt-get remove fdlrx
   sudo apt-get remove xdm
   sudo apt-get remove openvpn
   sudo apt-get remove bcmwl-kernel-source
   ```

   Last command, I take from this page only.
4. Then rebooted the system using command using command:

   ```
   reboot
   ```