# drm intel pipe_config_compare [i915] error mismatch in ips_enabled

Tags: boot, xubuntu, syslinux

Encountered error after install of xdm drm intel pipe_config_compare [i915] error mismatch in ips_enabled, right after startup. Searching the forms, found nothing useful. I had some config changes, and installed new soft xdm and screen etc. I new they were causing the issue but not how to fix. Read the second part.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/757696/530803

Answer (score 0):

Follow this post, it did the magic. https://askubuntu.com/a/757696/530803
Here is what you it says to do,

Steps I followed:- 1. When the error popped up, I press Ctrl + Alt + F3, it opens virtual terminal and entered my login and password.

Then use this command:- history | grep install
After this output shows, what all softwares I recently installed. mine shows fdlrx, xdm, openvpn.

Removed those softwares using command:- sudo apt-get remove fdlrx sudo apt-get remove xdm sudo apt-get remove openvpn sudo apt-get remove bcmwl-kernel-source
Last command, I take from this page only.

Then reboot the system using command using command:- reboot

And it will work. This post must be marked as answered so that it becomes easy to find. So I decided to create my own thread and mark it answered!

Answer (score 0):

You just have to install the official Intel Graphic Drivers:

[https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/intel-graphics-installer-linux-1.4.0)

After that, You need to add the required keys to apt

```
wget --no-check-certificate https://download.01.org/gfx/RPM-GPG-KEY-ilg-3 -O - | \
sudo apt-key add -
```

And finally, run the installer script:

```
sudo intel-linux-graphics-installer
```